# Why are gcp IAM permissions so open by default and what is a good common practice to restrict GCP bucket access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have a GCP cloud setup by someone else through the GCP console with the default permissions. There are some buckets, compute engine vms and cloud run services in there. I am moving it to terraform deployments, and want to tighten down the permissions. I see that by default, there are a number of service accounts that have permissions (service agent role bindings) at the project level, which means they have those permissions for everything in the project.
For instance the  `Compute Engine Service Agent` role has

```
storage.objects.create
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.list
storage.objects.update
```

and the `Cloud Run Service Agent` role has

```
storage.managedFolders.get
storage.managedFolders.list
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.list
```

If I understand it correctly, this means that any user/service account with those roles at the project level (which is the case for all the default service accounts), can access (and write to in the case of the `Compute Engine Service Account`) any file in any bucket in the project. I am making my own policies with specific bindings at the bucket level (while using uniform access and public access prevention) so  i keep control over specifically which roles can access the bucket and its contents, but it seems these project level permissions completely negate any effort i do at the resource (bucket) level to tighten down permissions.

Google seems to adhere to the [least privilege principle](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely), but then makes these permissions for service agent roles by default. So my questions are 2:

Do I really have to turn all of those default service agent roles (there are quite a lot, at least one role and one default service account for every service) into custom roles, remove the bindings of all default service agent roles from the default service accounts, and assign my custom roles to them instead, so they dont have access to all gcp buckets? That seems like a LOT of work, with a lot of potential for errors because I miss a privilege. I cant imagine the intention from google is to make me throw out all their default service agent roles and service accounts just to follow the least privilege principle on GCP Storage buckets.

If I am missing something here (I hope so) how then do I make sure that I can whitelist roles with IAM permissions on a bucket and not worry about what other default permissions and roles have project level storage permissions?

Comment: In order to restrict access, you can use [IAM conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#examples-resource) as they can allow you to create conditions for your IAM roles, which could be used to control the user access on specific buckets.Also, you can refer to the [best practices](https://sysdig.com/blog/gcp-security-best-practices/) blog written by Alejandro  Villanueva. Kindly go through the links and let me know if it is useful to you.

Comment: A key point - you should not modify service agent roles. Those service accounts are used by Google services to access required resources. They do not affect your services (or grant unnecessary permissions) to users, service accounts, compute resources, etc. For the other cases, grant least privilege to the principals that need to access resources. In many cases, each resource has its own IAM system so that you can grant access on a resource by resource basis. Study up on the difference between project-level IAM management and resource-level IAM management.

Comment: @JohnHanley The problem with that is that it breaks the "least privilige" principle. Some of those roles are used by default service accounts and have project level access to all gcs buckets and their objects (in some cases even write access). So if one of the default service accounts gets used for a service, that service WILL get all those permissions on any bucket, even the buckets it shouldn't. That is bad security practice. I dont want to depend on all admins to "remember" not to use a specific service account or default role because they have project level permissions on gcp storage.

Comment: @KiranKotturi I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but it doesnt help much. Conditions as I understand them are used to limit permissions I grant actively. My question is about overly permissive roles/service accounts that google creates by default. In the "security best practices" article  i cant find anything relevant for me. If I missed it, I would really appreciate it if you could point out what the relevant section is in that long article.

Comment: There are two types of deployed service accounts. Service Accounts you create and manage and Service Agents. My comment is about Service Agents. Do not modify Service Agents. They are managed by Google for you. Make sure you understand the difference. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents Regarding self-managed service accounts, once you have a solid understanding of IAM, delete the default ones and create service accounts specific to each service and use case.

Comment: Suggestion: posting questions that ask for opinions is not recommended on StackOverflow. Instead, post a specific problem that can be answered with facts or citations. There are many opinions on security. The appropriate level of security and method of deployment depends on many factors. There are tradeoffs with all security implementations.